# Check if combined data in multiple cells is duplicated in sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Forgive me, I may not the be best at explaining what I'm trying to write.

I have a sheet, it has data in cells J, K and M, N that I want to compare to see if there is any duplicate information. Specifically only when together. For example, I want to check to see if the combined data of J3 and K3 match any of the combinations of J4, K4 and any of the M and N combos. So, combine the data of two cells in two columns but the same row and then compare against all other combos.

I do not wish to actually combine the cells, they need to stay separate for other formulas.

If a set matches another set I want the program to notify me. So far I've come up with absolutely nothing. I can compare a cell to a cell but a set of cells in a range is tripping me up. Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Try the countifs function.

Answer (score 2):

Copy this to all the rows with data

```
=if(countifs($J:$J,$J1,$K:$K,$K1,$M:$M,$M1,$N:$N,$N1)>0,"Duplicate","Okay")
```

Edit: Include two additional formulas to check if duplicates among the same pairs

J and K

```
=if(countifs($J:$J,$J1,$K:$K,$K1)>0,"Duplicate","Okay")
```

M and N

```
=if(countifs($M:$M,$M1,$N:$N,$N1)>0,"Duplicate","Okay")
```

Comment: I can't get it to work in the formula, I think because there's formulas in the cells already so there's circular logic going on. Is there anyway to apply this to a VBA macro script?

Comment: this can be done in a VBA macro.  Without seeing the structure of the sheet it would be very hard to provide an exact solution for either method.  The countifs function above is the easiest and fastest way to a solution.